# React-native Stripe Payment Sheet with Subscription

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, subscription

I'm using [stripe-react-native](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native) to handle payment, and I'm able to handle one-time payment via payment-sheet using `PaymentIntent` flow.

Now I'm stuck with creating subscription using the same payment sheet flow, has anyone tried this before? Or an advise how to use `PaymentIntent` in subscription?

Comment: When you create a subscription on your backend you can expand on `latest_invoice.payment_intent` and you can send the `client_secret` of that `PaymentIntent` to the payment-sheet the same way you did for a normal `PaymentIntent`.

Comment: The latest_invoice only seems to provide the invoice ID and is not an object @Tarzan

Comment: @Tarzan can you convert your comment to an answer to accept it? and it would be lovely to provide some code examples. Thanks

Comment: You need to pass `expand: ['latest_invoice. payment_intent']` in create subscription then you will be able to get the  `client_secret` by `subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret` @EthanCrabb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expand the subscription object with payment intent.

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
  ...subscriptionSettings
  expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent']
});
```

You can then access it using:

```
const paymentIntent = subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent
const clientSecret = subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret
```